# How to get doctrine query stats from Symfony2 during page load

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to add a little stat to the footer of the page, along the lines of '184ms/6/10ms'.

Where 184ms is the page generation  time, 6 is the query count and 10 is the time taken for DB queries.

I can work out the page generation time, but how do I get the database stats out of doctrine?

This would be when running in the app environment of course, I appreciate when in app_dev, there probably is a way to get at it as the symfony profiler is running.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the DebugStack Object.

You will have an array with every query and their respective execution time.

Example :

```
    $doctrine = $this->get('doctrine');
    $doctrineConnection = $doctrine->getConnection();
    $stack = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack();
    $doctrineConnection->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger($stack);
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();

    ... // Perform query

    var_dump($stack);
```

Var dump of $stack example :

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack Object
(
    [queries] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sql] => SELECT t0.id AS id1 FROM Test t0
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [types] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [executionMS] => 0.00018191337585449
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sql] => SELECT t0.id AS id1 FROM Test t0
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [types] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [executionMS] => 0.00016307830810547
                )

        )

    [enabled] => 1
    [start] => 1426590420.2278
    [currentQuery] => 2
)
```

Comment: Yeah, its not a great way though in production as you log the SQL for all queries, all I want is the execution time.  I wonder if there is a way to implement your own 'debugstack' which just grabs the time and doesn't log all the SQL.

Thanks though, its a great pointer in the right direction.

Comment: I've managed to get it working, but its pointless. Because the page uses template "inheritance", the point at which the footer is rendered is half way through the process of rendering the page and it appears impossible to tell twig to render it last of all.

So basically, it appears impossible to display accurate page generation stats at the right time in a Symfony2 site, unless anyone can show me otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

First enable doctrine profiling in your `config.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        profiling: true
```

Create Twig Extension class like this:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.pgp

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\DebugStack;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var DebugStack
     */
    protected $debugStack;

    /**
     * AppExtension constructor.
     * @param DebugStack $debugStack
     */
    function __construct(DebugStack $debugStack)
    {
        $this->debugStack = $debugStack;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('request_time', [$this, 'requestTime'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('query_time', [$this, 'queryTime'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('query_count', [$this, 'queryCount'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Returns application execution time
     *
     * @param int $decimals
     * @return string
     */
    public function requestTime($decimals = 0)
    {
        return number_format((microtime(true) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'])*1000, $decimals);
    }

    /**
     * Returns doctrine query execution time
     *
     * @param int $decimals
     * @return string
     */
    public function queryTime($decimals = 2)
    {
            return number_format(array_sum(array_column($this->debugStack->queries, 'executionMS'))*1000, $decimals);
    }

    /**
     * Returns doctrine query count
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function queryCount()
    {
            return count($this->debugStack->queries);
    }
}
```

Register your extension in `services.yml`

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        arguments: ["@doctrine.dbal.logger.profiling.default"]
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Use it in twig main template as follow:

`{{ query_count() }}`, `{{ query_time() }}`, `{{ request_time() }}`

**Remember:**

If you put `{{ query_count() }}` or `{{ query_time() }}` in the beginning of your template, **it will not** show you all queries.

Best practice will be to put them in the end of your main template. If you want to show them in the beginning use **CSS**.

**Live Demo:** https://mysql-todolist.tk