# How to get Doctrine total queries execution time for MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony profiler, execution time is shown for MySQL queries but it's missing for **MongoDB**.

I'd like to add a little stat to the footer of the page. How to get total queries execution time for MongoDB queries?

The solution I am looking for is similar to [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096343/how-to-get-doctrine-query-stats-from-symfony2-during-page-load#answer-29097544).

Comment: In the past there was a pull request that would allow such functionality however [it was closed](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/pull/153#issuecomment-75864205) with resolution that driver's stream context logging proved more useful to the person working on this and the work was never continued.

Comment: I wrote a simple solution, but it looks like there is a problem with MongoDB's logging. When I set `profilingLevel` to `2`, I encountered a problem where my query for MongoDB logs overhead logged queries.